# Can helm `find-file` in the parents directory automatically?

Tags: helm, ido

With `ido-find-file`, if the file I am looking is not in current directory but in the parents directory, it can automatically find it as candidate. I am not sure if `helm` can do the same thing?

Comment: How do you do that with `ido-find-file`? It doesn't work for me. If you want something like that, use Helm and Projectile.

Comment: @TuDo It's the Ido [Auto-Merge feature](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length) which can be controlled using the `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` var.

Comment: @TuDo, I am using Emacs 25 and all by default setup for `ido`. I am reading Helm Wiki and find how to find file in the subdirectory not parents. The directory is not under version control so don't thing Projectile would help.

Comment: I don't think `helm-find-files` can do that and never will, since that behaviour of `ido-find-file` is confusing since it takes me to random location uncontrollably. You can use `C-c h` or `M-p` to list all visited directories though.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others in the comments, this probably isn't gong to happen. But I'll make a few suggestions that I hope might help you work with `helm` the way you want to.

This may be obvious, but if you are using `helm-find-file`, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. It sounds like you may know that already, but don't want to have to do it.

I tend to rely more on `helm-for-files` instead, and not think about what directory I am in at all. If your search string is only one word, any candidate in the parent directory will hopefully appear under the `locate` heading.

Finally, you may want to look further into `projectile` over [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile). You don't need to put a folder under version control to make it a project, just create an empty `.projectile` file in any parent directory you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your project is under Version Control, use `vc-root-dir` to find the root of the project.

If you look at `helm-find` function's implementation, it uses `helm-find-1` for the actual call to the find utility. So you can crank up your own interactive find function:

```
(defun helm-find-root ()
  (interactive)
  (helm-find-1 (vc-root-dir)))
```

Sprinkle it up with other goodies for best results.